# Add input types on random

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-controls

I have a input type number. Once the user enters the number in that field. I want to generate that many input types under it. How can I do it with javascript or Ajax for that matter.

```
<table width="100%">
    No of Plans:
    <input type="text" name="numbers" value="" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>  //using AUI here to check if numbers only
    //If the number is 5 say. I need to generate 5 input fields under here.
```

My Javascript which will check that the user enters only numbers is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

All this is working for me. I just need the loop which would generate input fields as the value entered in `numbers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should help:

```
function createInputs() {
    var num = 123, // <-- user-defined
        i,
        input,
        body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    for (i = 0, i < num; i++) {
        input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";

        // Add to the DOM
        body.appendChild(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I call this function you suggested on submit. 

This is my submit here

    <td><input type="submit" value="Create" name="button"     style="width: 80px;" class="rightButtons" ></td>  `

Comment: Simply add: `onsubmit="createInputs();"` to your `input` element. If you want to add the new `input`s at a different point (i.e. not at the end of the `body`) just change the name and value of the `body` variable in my example.

Answer (score 1):

you can use create element to create input elements dynamically

refer this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript.html

```
function addElement(eletype){
    var ele = document.createElement("input");
    ele.setAttribute("type", eletype);
    //id is the id1 of the div or any component in which you want to add this element
    var baseele = document.getElementById("id1");
    baseele.appendChild(ele);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You find good help here

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript.html